# Asp.Net FormAuth Dynamic LoginUrl

Tags: asp.net, authentication

How can I change loginurl using Forms Auth?

I am using web.config to configure all permissions.

At root web.config, I set login url. Now I need to change loginurl at a subfolder, but ASP.NET give me a error if I try to re-configure  at inner web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get this to work (to my knowledge) would be to configure the subfolder as a virtual/application directory, which will allow you to place another web.config in that directory.